# Fill datetime-local input field

Tags: angular, form-fields

I want to set the value of a datetime-local input field in my component class but I cannot bind the value.

What I am missing?

HTML

```
<input id="date" type="datetime-local" [(ngModel)]="model.date" class="form-control" />
```

TS

```
public model: Model = new Model(-1, "old", new Date(2000, 1,1 ));
```

Here is a example [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/1MxbZA?p=preview).

The datetime-local input field has no value (Chrome 55)
[image: datetime-local has no value]

Comment: Plunker. is running as expected what is your task ?

Comment: @anshuVersatile no it isn't, Click on **Fill Fiels** button, it doesn't fill date of form field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use string format for `this.model.date`, I changed your plunker and `fill fields` now works fine.
https://plnkr.co/edit/FpEBvc?p=preview

Comment: To get the formatted time you could use `moment` for example.